# How to change a label when a desired process is running

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check if a process is running or not then display it within the application in a form of text. In this case If the process is not found, the application will display "Process not found" vs when its running, "Process is running"...

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgcPB.png)

Here's my current code:

```
    Dim p() As Process

    Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName("iw5sp")
        If p.Count > 0 Then
            ' Status: Game Not Found!
        Else
            ' Status: Game Found!
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Those comments are backwards.

Comment: You have to show us more code and explain the context if you want help finding why it doesn't work. The code itself that you have posted works, so the issue must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless searches, people being undermost unhelpful, and the 100% dis-votes, I finally present to you a solution! Works on VB.Net! Simple make a label, Insert this code. BOOM. All code was original other from ReadWritingMemory.vb.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Timer1 As New Timer

    Public Function IsProcessRunning(Notepad As String) As Boolean
        For Each clsProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith(Notepad) Then
                Return True
            Else
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function
    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Run As Integer
        If Run = 0 Then
            AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
            Timer1.Interval = 1
            Timer1.Start()

        Else
            RemoveHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim p() As Process
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
        If p.Count > 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "Status: Notepad Running!"
            Label1.Refresh()
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Status: Notepad Not Running!"
            Label1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Be sure to have ReadWritingMemory.vb added to your class.
Code for that found [here](https://pastebin.com/KF3vvZ7s).

Visual Context:

[image: Example 1: Not running]
[image: Example 1: running]